# <v-navigation-drawer> has come to the side of the footer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3

I would like to dynamically set the height value of a style that I set to an element. Specifically, when scrolling to the bottom, the height of the height is 77.5%, when the footer element is not visible at all, it is 100%, and when the footer is visible, it is the visible value I want to subtract the height from 100%.
I tried various things with handleScroll below, but I can't adjust the height well. Please let me know if there is a way to adjust

```
.v-navigation-drawer {
  height: 77.5% !important;
}
```

Below is the full code.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <Header />
    <!-- <TableofContents /> -->
    <v-navigation-drawer width="300" border="r" app> test </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <slot />
      </v-container>
      <NavigationLink />
    </v-main>
    <v-footer border="t">
      <v-row justify="center" no-gutters>
        <AppThemeToggle />
        <v-col class="primary lighten-2 py-4 text-center white--text" cols="12">
          <strong
            >Copyright {{ new Date().getFullYear() }} vuetify
            Corporation</strong
          >
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

[image: screen shot]

When I put the footer in v-main, it became as follows.

```
<v-main>
      <v-container>
        <slot />
        <NavigationLink />
        <v-footer
          border="t"
          style="position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; z-index: 9999"
        >
          <v-row justify="center" no-gutters>
            <AppThemeToggle />
            <v-col
              class="primary lighten-2 py-4 text-center white--text"
              cols="12"
            >
              <strong
                >Copyright {{ new Date().getFullYear() }} vuetify
                Corporation</strong
              >
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-footer>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
```

[image]

If the content of the navigation covers the footer, I would like to scroll it like the image below

[image]

Comment: does the vuetify `v-navigation-drawer` component have the class `v-navigation-drawer`? or did you just assume it would?

Comment: What does `height of the height is 75%` mean ??? If you know the height of the footer (e.g. 64px), you can set the height as `<v-navigation-drawer height="calc(100% - 64px)">`

Comment: @JaromandaX
.v-navigation-drawer is the default class for the <v-navigation-drawer> component

Comment: @IVOGELOV
Because setting it to 75% puts the v-navigation-drawer above the footer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want the navbar between header and footer:

```
------------                ------------
|  header  |                |  header  |
------------                ------------ 
| n |      |                | n |      |
| a | main |    instead of  | a | main |
| v |      |                | v |      |
------------                |   |-------
|  footer  |                |   | foot |
------------                ------------
```

[Layout components](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/application-layout/) like VAppBar, VNavigationDrawer or VFooter (with [`:app`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-footer/#props-app) prop) work by claiming space in order they are declared, except for VMain, which will always claim the leftover space. So in above example, the left one has order header-footer-nav, while the right one has order header-nav-footer (same as your example).

So instead of manually adjusting height, just change the order of the elements:

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar />
    <v-footer app> ... </v-footer>
    <v-navigation-drawer> ... </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-main> ... </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

```js
Vue.createApp({}).use(Vuetify.createVuetify()).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar>header</v-app-bar>
    <v-footer app border="t"> footer </v-footer>
    <v-navigation-drawer border="r" permanent>drawer</v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-main class="bg-grey"> Main content </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you want the footer to scroll with the main content, you cannot use the app footer, as it is fixed on the page. I don't think there is an elegant solution to get the footer inside main yet over the nav bar. But you can put the footer into `v-main` and set absolute position on it:

```html
<v-app>
  <v-app-bar>...</v-app-bar>
  <v-navigation-drawer>...</v-navigation-drawer>
  <v-main>
    ...
    <v-footer style="position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; z-index: 9999;"
    >...</v-footer>
  </v-main>
</v-app>
```

see [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: thank you.
Improved.
However, if you use <v-footer app>, the footer will continue to be displayed even if you scroll.
Is it possible to show the footer when scrolling to the bottom?

Comment: Hmm, getting the footer inside the scrollable content of v-main but over the navbar can only be done by fiddling with positioning. Have a look at the updated answer

Comment: I attached a screenshot with <v-footer> inside <v-main> in the question text.
In this case the content inside the <v-navigation-drawer> is hidden by the footer

Comment: That's what you wanted, right? Reduce the height of the navigation so the footer takes up the whole width?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
I added what I want to achieve to the question text.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me carefully. I'll try to find a way without using v-navigation-drawer.